# What is difference between vhDir :Network and Organization in FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

How we need to query Network(vhdir Resource) from Organization endpoint

How we differentiate Network & Organization

Reference : http://build.fhir.org/ig/HL7/VhDir/StructureDefinition-vhdir-network.html

Answer (score 1):

That's a very good question.  There doesn't seem to be any element in the resource that clearly distinguishes 'network' organizations from other organizations.  It is *not* safe to use meta.profile to distinguish.  Profile declarations can't ever declare semantics not already present in the instance.  I.e. if you wiped all profile declarations, it should be possible to determine whether an instance was a network or not irrespective of the profile.

I'd suggest submitting a change request against the implementation guide requiring a pattern be set on Organization.code that clearly distinguishes network organizations from other organizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `GET [base]/Organization?_profile=http://hl7.org/fhir/uv/vhdir/StructureDefinition/vhdir-network`.

This will filter the Organizations on the profile url listed in the Organization.meta.profile field. Any Organization that is a network and conforms to the vhdir-network profile should have that field filled in accordingly.